# Geoserver and OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, html, postgresql, openlayers, geoserver

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">

<head>
  <title>Openlayers test</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.0.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v6.0.1/css/ol.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
  <style>
    .map {
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#document").ready(function() {
      var format = 'image/png';

      var bounds = [185100.3262864739, 939575.001675438,
        830327.599490219, 2583234.181646719
      ];
      var ThuaDat = new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          ratio: 1,
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/decuong_doan/wms',
          params: {
            'FORMAT': format,
            'VERSION': '1.1.1',
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'decuong_doan:ho_chi_minh_quan',
          }
        })
      });
      var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:3405',
        units: 'm',
        axisOrientation: 'neu'
      });
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          ThuaDat
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: projection
        })
      });
      //map.getView().fitExtent(bounds, map.getSize());
      map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="map" class="map"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

I'm trying to get a WebGIS. but when I wrote this code, it didn't run just open in browser white. below is this code. :( it really a big problem for me so can anyone help me, please.

This is a layer preview. So I want to import this layers in WebGIS. I get this code but it does not run.

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPtA8.png)

Comment: You need to define and register your projection using proj4  See this example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/wms-image-custom-proj.html

Comment: :( i still dont understand. so in my code i use link openlayers library but pro4js use import something?

Comment: If all coordinates are in the same projection it is possible to do it without proj4 https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/wms-no-proj.html  It might be your axisOrientation is the problem - this definition has it E-N https://epsg.io/3405

Comment: oh, thanks a lot. maybe this is answer for my question. I am not really sure. But I will try it, <3

Comment: hi Mike, can you give me your link FaceBook account. :( facilitate the conversation. plsssss